# .NET EEPLUS ExcelPackage DataValidation ListValidation fails with large lists

Tags: .net, validation, excelpackage

I'm using EEPLUS to export a preformated-excel using for that DataValidation Lists, but I'm getting Error in a large List, here is the code:

```
        ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Testing");

        ws.Cells["A1"].Value = "Column A";
        ws.Cells["B1"].Value = "Column B";
        ws.Cells["C1"].Value = "Column C";
        ws.Cells["A1:C1"].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
        ws.Cells["A1:C1"].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.FromArgb(184, 204, 228));
        ws.Cells["A1:C1"].Style.Font.Bold = true;

        var val = ws.DataValidations.AddListValidation("B2:B10000");
        val.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Add");
        val.Formula.Values.Add("Delete");

        var val2 = ws.DataValidations.AddListValidation("C2:C10000");
        val2.ShowErrorMessage = true;
        foreach (var student in classroomDictionary) val2.Formula.Values.Add(student["Name"]);

        Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=etiquetas-{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")));
```

As you can see, I'm creating 3 columns where the 2nd and 3r with DataValidation ListValidation. 
The 2nd column works great, but the 3r which I'm adding 200 items creates the Excel Workbook but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to oppening. There is a limitation for the numbers of items? Is a Excel limitation or EEPLUS limitation or is a problem with my code?
[image: In english something like: Excel found content that cannot be reading in... Do you want to recover the book content?...]

In english sais something like: Excel found content that cannot be reading in... Do you want to recover the book content?...

Thank you
BR

Comment: _What_ error do you get?

Comment: I put the Excel error message in the post, is in spanish sorry, I tried to translate it. Tks

Comment: What happens if you click "Si"? Does it work, do you get details what went wrong, what features were removed?

Comment: Opens the Excel saying "featured removed data validation" and no lists in the excel worksheet. But If I comment the "val2" code and try again, the excel open correctly  with the first validation list also correctly and no error messages.